# No service for type UserIdentity has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a web application where I want to integrate ASP.NET Core Identity but after adding controllers and views and editing the _Layout.cshtml I get this error:

InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[StrikeNet.EntityFramework.Entities.UserIdentity]' has been registered.

When I search for this error on Google or on here I only get the solution to rename all instances of IdentityUser to the name I have given, being UserIdentity. Also, many solutions say I should find it in the _LoginPartial.cshtml file.

The problem is, I don't have a file in my solution called _LoginPartial.cshtml and when I use the ctrl + F search tool and search for IdentityUser I also get no results.

Any ideas on what could be the remaining problem?

Comment: Have you updated Startup.cs to contain configuration for Identity to your service collection? eg: services.AddIdentity, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add Identity into Startup.cs configuration:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(); // if you have roles
```

Comment: This was indeed the missing step. I have followed a tutorial the previous time but did it out of my head this time and accidentally skipped this. Thanks for pointing out:)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, I don't have a file in my solution called _LoginPartial.cshtml

I would suggest you create the asp.net core application with  Identity template : Create ASP.NET Core web application -->Change Authentication --> choose Individual User Accounts . Ater visual studio help creating application with identity enabled , you can check the dbcontext , pages and startup file to find difference with your exist application . After copying the missing files , you can create your user entity inheriting from `IdentityUser` :

```
public class UserIdentity: IdentityUser
{
}
```

Modify the `ApplicationDbContext` :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<UserIdentity>
{
}
```

Modify Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddDefaultIdentity<UserIdentity>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

And update the _LoginPartial :

```
@inject SignInManager<UserIdentity> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<UserIdentity> UserManager
```

You can also refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) for more details .